# How can I synchronize files using R that have different sampling frequencies (Hz)?

Tags: r

I have two different files, one of which is EMG data sampled at 1500Hz. The other file is a basically a trigger signal that is relevant for the EMG data, sampled at 1000Hz. In order to analyze the EMG data, I need to know when the triggers from the 1000Hz file occur. I want to combine the files, both at 1000Hz I guess, and I am not sure how to do so. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

So far I have tried:

```
fs_old <- 1500
fs_new <- 1000
emg_data_new_fs <- emg_data %>%
  select(starts_with("muscle")) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  t() %>%
  resample(fs_new, fs_old) %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(paste0("muscle_", 1:ncol(.)))
```

But this doesn't work, and I end up with a file with a bunch of columns with only one observation. I would like to just change the sampling rate of the 1500Hz file and add it to the other, keeping the original columns side by side.

Answer (score 0):

I would use linear interpolation.  There is an implementation in base R with the `approx()` function.  The syntax would be something like

`y2 <- approx(x1, y1, x2)$y`

Where `x1` and `y1` are the time and value vectors from one frequency and `x2` is the time vector for the other frequency.  I guess it's up to you which frequency you want to interpolate to.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# simulate data
origin <- as_date("1970-01-01")

high_freq <- tibble(
  freq = "high",
  tme = Sys.time() + seconds(seq(0, 1000, by = 10)),
  x = as.double(tme, origin = origin),
  y = sin(x * 1e-2)
)

low_freq <- tibble(
  freq = "low",
  tme = Sys.time() + seconds(seq(0, 1000, by = 100)),
  x = as.double(tme, origin = origin),
  y = as.numeric(scale(x))
)

bind_rows(high_freq, low_freq) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(tme, y) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~freq, ncol = 1, labeller = label_both) + 
  ggtitle("both low and high freq")
```

[image]

```r
# low freq values interpolated to high freq axis
high_freq$z <- approx(low_freq$x, low_freq$y, high_freq$x)$y

high_freq %>%
  rename(high = y, low = z) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(high, low), names_to = "frequ") %>%
  ggplot() + aes(tme, value) + geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) + facet_wrap(~frequ, ncol = 1, labeller = label_both) + 
  ggtitle("low freq values interpolated to high freq axis")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Do I need to use both x1 and y1? How do the time and value vectors differ?